# IntelliJ run configurations for Netbeans RCP project

Tags: maven, netbeans, intellij-idea, netbeans-platform, run-configuration

there's a project I'm working on with a team ([BUMMEL](https://github.com/Uko/BUMMEL)) and we've migrated it's build tool from Ant to Maven, to make it IDE-agnostic, and now I can open it into IntelliJ as a Maven project but I have troubles creating the run configuration for it.

Can anyone suggest me how to create a Run configuration? Also any other suggestions about running NetBeans-RCP maven-based project on IntelliJ are appreciated.

Comment: What problem do you have with the Run configuration? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yes, I've never wrote a run configurations. Always use a green "Play" arrow in Netbeans toolbar

Comment: In your class where you have your main method you can right click and select Run or Debug. I'm not at my computer right now so don't know exact names. (This is just one way to do it. There are others)

Comment: @maba I know about that, but I don't know where is the main class in Netbeans RCP and I have no idea whether I should do something related to Maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you should go to `Edit Configurations...` and **add** new Maven configuration.

Then put in *Working directory:* field a path you your app module, for me its `application/` in the project root.

And in *Command line:* field put `nbm:cluster-app nbm:run-platform`.

Now you can run your app by selecting a newly created configuration and pressing a green "Play" arrow.